# How can I not show the border lines before the output is executed?

Tags: javascript, html, function, border

I am trying to hide the border of my div style because I have a div id to be put in that style but the border is showing before I click the button to execute the div id by a button.

This is for one of my assignments. Everything works fine other than this design flaw I have.

I am a complete beginner so may seem like a dumb question.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Old MacDonald Verse</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function OldMacVerse(animal,sound)
            {
            
                 document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
                '<p>Old Macdonald had a farm, E-I-E-I-O.<br>' +
                'And on that farm he had a ' + animal + ', E-I-E-I-O. <br>' +
                'With a ' + sound + '-' + sound + ' here, and a ' + sound + '-' + sound +
                ' there, <br>' + ' here a ' + sound + ', there a ' + sound + 
                ', everywhere a ' + sound + '-' + sound + '.<br>' + 
                'Old Macdonald had a farm, E-I-E-I-O.</p>';
                                                                                       
            }
        </script>

        <body> 
            <div style= "border: solid; margin: auto; width:350px; text-align: center;">
            <h1>Old MacDonald Verse</h1>
            <input type="button" value="Pig Verse"
            onclick="OldMacVerse('pig','oink');">
            <input type="button" value="Sheep Verse"
            onclick="OldMacVerse('sheep','baa');">
            <input type="button" value="Cow Verse"
            onclick="OldMacVerse('cow', 'moo');">
        </div>

            <br>

        <div style= "border: groove; margin: auto; width: 350px; text-align: center;">
        </div>
        <div id="outputDiv">
        </div>

    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Your html is not properly formatted, please add the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class for your output div:

```
<style>
.myclass {
   border: groove;
}
</style>
```

And apply the class dynamically in your function:

```
function OldMacVerse(animal, sound) {
   // ...
   var element = document.getElementById("outputDiv");
   element.classList.add("myclass");
   // ...
}
```

And remove the style from the external div.

Complete code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Old MacDonald Verse</title>

    <style>
        .myclass {
            border: groove;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="border: solid; margin: auto; width:350px; text-align: center;">
        <h1>Old MacDonald Verse</h1>
        <input type="button" value="Pig Verse" onclick="OldMacVerse('pig','oink');">
        <input type="button" value="Sheep Verse" onclick="OldMacVerse('sheep','baa');">
        <input type="button" value="Cow Verse" onclick="OldMacVerse('cow', 'moo');">
    </div>

    <br>

    <div style="margin: auto; width: 350px; text-align: center;">
    </div>
    <div id="outputDiv">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OldMacVerse(animal, sound) {
            var element = document.getElementById("outputDiv");
            element.classList.add("myclass");

            element.innerHTML =
                '<p>Old Macdonald had a farm, E-I-E-I-O.<br>' +
                'And on that farm he had a ' + animal + ', E-I-E-I-O. <br>' +
                'With a ' + sound + '-' + sound + ' here, and a ' + sound + '-' + sound +
                ' there, <br>' + ' here a ' + sound + ', there a ' + sound +
                ', everywhere a ' + sound + '-' + sound + '.<br>' +
                'Old Macdonald had a farm, E-I-E-I-O.</p>';

        }
    </script>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Would I put the class before the function? I am just really new so still learning. Then apply the class to my function after the internal HTML?

Comment: I have included the complete code on my answer. First thing you have to do is separate the `head` and the `body` of the page. The `<style>` block goes inside the `head` and the `<script>` can go inside the `body`.